# Invoke-WebRequest causes IE content blocked dialog

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

On a Windows server with [Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815141) enabled, calling Invoke-WebRequest like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://localhost" -UseBasicParsing -UseDefaultCredentials
```

Results in this error dialog:

[image: Internet Explorer dialog - Content within this application coming from the website listed below is being blocked by Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration]

Considering that this script is intended to be run remotely, I'd like to avoid the dialog appearing at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click Add and add `about:security_powershell.exe` to `Trusted Sites`.

Comment: A good suggestion - I tried that. I then get subsequent errors relating to other files that the initial page references. Looks like Invoke-WebRequest is behaving like a regular browser, rather than just retrieving the initial request's content

Comment: That's exactly what `Invoke-WebRequest` does. You can use `System.Net.WebClient` as an alternative but there will be no client-side processing there(no ajax).

Comment: Exactly what I ended up using :-)

Comment: In my case adding `about:/assets/default.js` to Trusted Sites was also required.

Comment: but this defeats automation. The OP stated he is trying to execute remotely.

Comment: This is not a solution for script automation as it involves UI!

Answer (score 23):

It seems **Invoke-WebRequest** requires IE unless you specify -UseBasicParsing parameter. 
see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Invoke-WebRequest

> **-UseBasicParsing** Indicates that the cmdlet uses the response object for HTML content
>   without Document Object Model (DOM) parsing.
>
> This parameter is required when Internet Explorer is not installed on
>   the computers, such as on a Server Core installation of a Windows
>   Server operating system.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the opposite? If "this parameter is required when IE is _not_ installed...".

Comment: This didn't work for me. Adding -UseBasicParsing still resulted in the IE ESC pop-up for new URLs; at least at PowerShell 3.0.

Comment: I saw this in the documentation: This parameter has been deprecated. Beginning with PowerShell 6.0.0, all Web requests use basic parsing only. This parameter is included for backwards compatibility only and any use of it has no effect on the operation of the cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps systems have changed since Raf's answer above was posted.  I found it didn't work for me.

What did work was:-

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Go to Tools->Internet options
3. Select the Security Tab
4. Click Local Intranet
5. Click sites
6. Enter *.security_powershell.exe
7. Click Add

Comment: I didn't have the "Add..." button shown in the OP's screenshot but otherwise the same error message, and this worked for me as well (though I added a different page to _Trusted Sites_ instead of _Local Intranet_).

Comment: OP is showing he is looking for a PowerShell based solution and it must be able to execute remotely. Why would you suggest a GUI solution? This defeats automation.

Comment: @Steven my understanding of the question is that they're attempting to run a powershell script on the client not the server.  If you don't want to use a GUI on the client to make these changes to the security policy you can use Windows Server Group Policy to apply security changes to all the machines within a domain

Answer (score 0):

Just return a single property of the object that comes back from the call, ie:

```
(invoke-webrequest -Uri https://www.google.com).RawContent

(invoke-webrequest -Uri https://www.google.com).StatusDescription
```

I don't really know what the default call for invoke-webrequest is doing, but it must be doing a lot more than just getting a raw HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am posting on very old post.

I am also getting this issue "Invoke-WebRequest causes IE content blocked dialog"
and option "Click Add and add about:security_powershell.exe to Trusted Sites." isn't working for me because I am hitting web-site in loop by passing parameter. so every time there will be new URL, like below. Any idea to permanently unblock and suppress this dialog box.

```
 #$URL='https://www.mywebsite.com/page/Public.aspx?id='+$CODE+'&qtr=8&Qtr=December'
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30095365)